# Which AT commands are supported by HUAWEI MS2372h-153 4G Industrial Dongle?

Tags: at-command, huawei-mobile-services, dongle

I want to use HUAWEI MS2372h-153 4G Industrial Dongle on a raspberry pi 4 in order to get cellular data like cell id, mnc, mcc, rsrq , rsrp , rssi, rscp and arfcn.

According to its data-sheet that I found here
https://www.secomea.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/ms2372h153_brief_datasheet.pdf
it is mentioned that regarding AT commands : 3GPP TS 27.007 and 27.005 Huawei extended AT command is supported.

However I haven't found neither a document that refers explicitly to this module nor a generic document for Huawei AT commands.

The only documents I found are the following :

- http://download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=51047&version=120450&siteCode
- http://download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=100630&version=432889&siteCode=cn&view=true

which refer to HUAWEI ME906s LTE M.2  and HUAWEI ME909s Series LTE Module.

Does anyone know which at command set is supported by this dongle ?

Comment: Indirect help: issue `AT+CLAC` and the list of supported commands will be printed.